# Worldbuilding's writing a blog post about TRAPPIST-1. What should we include in it?

Tags: discussion

Yes, this meta question is on the right site. Trust me.

Worldbuilding Stack Exchange has [a blog](https://medium.com/universe-factory), and [it was suggested](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/35626109#35626109) that we put together a post about [the recent discovery of four more planets around TRAPPIST-1](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v542/n7642/full/nature21360.html). I'm going to try to write it up the next couple days, and we'll probably publish it in a couple weeks (though no promises).

We also want to <strike>steal</strike> take inspiration from content on Astronomy Stack Exchange about [TRAPPIST-1](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=TRAPPIST-1), especially since we've gotten a slew of questions about it in the last 24 hours. The point of all this is that it would be fantastic if members of the Astronomy Stack Exchange community could give us some ideas to work with. I've already read through the discovery paper, but obviously, plenty of folks here know more about TRAPPIST-1 and exoplanets in general than I do.

So, what would you like us to put in the post? Discussions of orbital stability? The formation of the planets outside the frost line? A brief overview of ultracool dwarfs? Liquid water? Something else entirely?

We want to use this blog post to promote cross-site interactions, and also to give some publicity to Astronomy Stack Exchange.

Comment: Cloned on Space Exploration: http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/q/847/58

Comment: Kim Holder has presented a wonderful answer over at SX: http://meta.space.stackexchange.com/a/849/58